# Inconsistent behavior with "guard method" within DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, datagrid, caliburn.micro

I have a `DataGrid` similar to this one:

```
<sdk:DataGrid ItemSource="ItemGroups">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Button 
                            Content="Show Items" 
                            cal:Message.Attach="ShowItems($dataContext)" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </sdk:DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}" Header="Name" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

In my view model I have a guard method:

```
public bool CanShowItems(ItemGroup itemGroup)
    {
        return itemGroup.State == States.Active;
    }
```

In my current scenario the guard method returns **true** for only the second item in the list.

All the other "ShowItems" button are disabled as they should be.

However, when I scroll down the DataGrid as the enabled button goes out of view another enabled button comes into view. There won't be two enabled buttons visible at the same time. But, again, there is only one call to the guard method that returns **true**.

What could be causing this odd behavior?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely caused by the fact that the `DataGrid` and similar controls recycle `DataTemplate`s. This causes some issues similar to what you are describing. In general, I would avoid putting actions directly on rows. That can result in a lot of behaviors being created, especially if you have a lot of data. You might need to a different approach altogether.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is only with the guard method. The action receives the correct $dataContext. Changing my approach at this point would be soooo painful.